# Mongoose.findOneAndUpdate is failing to run

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await, graphql

So I'm working on a graphql server and I'm trying to make an async/await external call to facebook's server.

The issue is that all this information does come back but it does not save to the db.
How do I know it does come back? if I use `findOne` instead of `findOneAndUpdate` I can `console.log` all the info and see it successfully but once I switch back I don't even get an error.

I have looked at the mongoose docs and tried to apply the `findOneAndUpdate` properly but it just laughs at me no error it just doesn't do anything.

Any way here is my code if any one can give me some advice it would really be appreciated.

The first set is code using `findOne` which I know works 100% but does not save or update the doc.

The second one is when I try to do it with `FindOneAndUpdate`.

```
getFacebookPageID: {
      type: FacebookType,
      description: 'Gets all the content we want from facebook once a user has granted permissions',
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQLString },
        accessToken: { type: GraphQLString },
        facebook: { type: InputFacebookType }
      },
      resolve: (parent, args) => User.findOne({ _id: args.id }, async (err, docs) => {
        console.log('next step is getcontent');
        // const clientId = process.env.FACEBOOK_ID;
        // const reDirectFBUri = process.env.FACEBOOK_ID_URI;
        const { accessToken } = docs.tokens.find((item) => item.kind === 'facebook');
        const userId = docs.facebookId;

        console.log(userId);
        const getFBaccounts = `https://graph.facebook.com/${userId}/accounts?access_token=${accessToken}`;
        let pages = null;
        await axios.get(getFBaccounts)
          .then((response) => {
            pages = response.data.data;
            // this above line is all the fb pages user has give us access to
            console.log('pages', response.data.data);
            const query = { _id: args.id, };
            console.log('This should be object id', query);
            User.updateOne(query, {
              pages,
            }, (err, docs) => {
              console.log('Any errors here are problems with saving!', err, docs);
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));


        return FacebookType;
      }
      ),
    },
```

I have also tried this below and that simply will not even console log anything. This is me trying to use `findOneAndUpdate`

```
getFacebookPageID: {
type: FacebookType,
description: 'Gets all the content we want from facebook once a user has granted permissions',
args: {
  id: { type: GraphQLString },
  accessToken: { type: GraphQLString },
  facebook: { type: InputFacebookType }
},
resolve: (parent, args) =>  User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: args.id },{ pages:  async (err, docs) => {
  console.log('next step is getcontent');

  const { accessToken } = docs.tokens.find((item) => item.kind === 'facebook');
  const userId = docs.facebookId;

  console.log(userId);
  const getFBaccounts = `https://graph.facebook.com/${userId}/accounts?access_token=${accessToken}`;
  let pages = null;
  await axios.get(getFBaccounts)
    .then((response) => {
      pages = response.data.data;

      console.log('pages', response.data.data);

    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));


  return FacebookType;
}
},
{new: true}
),
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use async/await in mix with promises. You should choose one approach (I suggest async/await);

```
resolve: async (parent, args) => {
try {
  //get user
  const user = await User.findById(args.id); //user is mongooose instance - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save
  const { accessToken } = user.tokens.find((item) => item.kind === 'facebook');
  const userId = user.facebookId;
  const getFBaccounts = `https://graph.facebook.com/${userId}/accounts?access_token=${accessToken}`;

  //get pages
  const fbResponse = await axios.get(getFBaccounts);

  //use mongoose prototype method "save" to update the user
  user.pages = fbResponse.data.data;
  await user.save();
  return user;
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
 }
}
```

Comment: tried the code before thia and the code after you edited .and I'm getting console logs but no data is actually saved

Comment: could you check if "fbResponse.data.data;" exists? Did you add pages type to mongoose schema?

Comment: so continued tinkering with the code you gave me and then changed a few things in the user model and voila it works ...thank you so much for helping

Comment: Yeah I think all along one of my major problems was that I was accessing the data wrongly so I have a facebook array that should contain a property pages that should have an array of objects and i think that is where i screwed the pooch but this really helps clarify things :)